# How to find if a name is in a mongodb in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to figure out how to get all of the items in a mongodb if they are matching what is trying to be found.

For example, if I want the name with "Steve" and I put "St" it will return "Steve"

I have tried:

```
Name.find({ name: /St/ })
```

where Name is require from my mongoose model.

When I do .find it seems to return a lot of stuff and not just the name. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
So after doing

`console.log(Name.find({ name: { $regex: '^Jacob' } }, { _id: 1 }));`
I get this:

````
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: undefined,
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: [Object],
      capped: false,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'names',
    collectionName: 'names',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 1,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: true,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _queue: [],
      _listening: false,
      _connectionString: '',
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise],
      name: 'Cluster0',
      host: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.cgc8h.mongodb.net',
      port: 27017,
      user: 'admin',
      pass: 'admin',
      db: [Db]
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { Name },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: { name: [Object] },
    paths: { name: [SchemaString], _id: [ObjectId], __v: [SchemaNumber] },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      name: [Object],
      _id: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 1,
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: { toJSON: [Object] },
    options: {
      toJSON: [Object],
      typePojoToMixed: true,
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      noVirtualId: false,
      _id: true,
      noId: false,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      optimisticConcurrency: false,
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strictQuery: false,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true
  },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { name: { '$regex': '^Jacob' } },
  _fields: { _id: 1 },
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: NativeCollection {
      collection: [Collection],
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'names',
      collectionName: 'names',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: false,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'names'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true,
  _userProvidedFields: { _id: 1 }
}``` 

I am looking to just return the name which in this case would be Jacob. What am I doing wrong?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caret `^` matches at the beginning of the text,

```
Name.find({ name: /^St/ })
```

Similar with [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
Name.find({ name: { $regex: "^St" } })
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f8ULXJn8Thw)

Comment: So when I do that it gives me a list of a bunch of stuff. I tried doing this: ```console.log(Name.find({ name: { $regex: '^Jacob' } }, { _id: 1 }));``` and it listed a bunch of stuff I just added to the edit.

Comment: You have to wrap that in async function and put await before like `console.log(await Name.find({...`, if you don't know about async/await please learn it before this.